# silverlight 4 and Layout Styles

Tags: silverlight, layout, expander

Does anybody knows what layout styles has been used on Silverlight toolkit website.
Specially the Two Regions on Right Hand Side with Expandable and multiple tab items on it.
http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

Can we use that?

Comment: Do you mean the left hand side? I can't see anything on the right hand side that is expandable with multiple tab items.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side uses the [Accordian control](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Control%20Overview%20Pg1&referringTitle=Home) which is freely available in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528)

For the right hand side I might guess that they are using a tab control with the tabs styled to appear at the bottom of the control.

For the overall layout, you can use a grid control with two columns and a [GridSplitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(VS.95).aspx) to enable the user to adjust the width.

Comment: When you select a Control from left side, it shows details on the Right side. The Top Region shows the info about control and sample Whereas the Bottom Regin which is Collapse/Expandle displays the code. I would like to know 
1) How Can I develope something like that (two panes adjustable and the bottom one when clicked on header can be expanded).
2) In the Bottom pane when expanded, can have multiple items as tabs like in this page where U have three links (.xaml file, .cs file and .sln file)